# hide password node.js MySQL data insert

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I have a variable that stores "score" and "highscore" on my website (https://gameplatform.ml/) using local storage. It works perfectly, but I want to make a public scoreboard (that everyone can see).

I found this: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp, but how can I prevent that people can just see my js code and see my password with Google's developers tool?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ('Company Inc', 'Highway 37')";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
  });
});
```

So my question is how I can hide the password. Or is their another way to insert data to a database?

EDIT:
[image]
So if I put the code in the GameCanva.js nobody is going to see my password? (@David and @Apoorva Chikara)

Comment: This is server-side code, users shouldn't be able to see it anyway.  It's not really clear to me what the problem is.

Comment: They can't see the API where you are making requests to DB, the client can only see the code on the browser and I don't see any passwords on the webpage you added.

Comment: Regarding the edit... Anything you put in *client-side* code will be visible to the client.  But *server-side* code wouldn't be (unless you've somehow exposed that code for users to download, which hopefully you're not doing).  You certainly shouldn't be putting database connection code client-side because you *probably* don't want to give users access to your database.  It sounds like you are in general misunderstanding the difference between code that runs on the server and code that runs on the client.

Comment: @David, I know, but how do you maken server side code? I don't understand where I have to put it, because if I run the code in my html file, I have to link it to the js code right? And then, they can just go to the js file right?

Comment: @Arthur2: You can start with some introductory tutorials on Node and Express (a popular web server framework built for Node).  There are lots of other frameworks and libraries you might use depending on what you build, but for using JavaScript and Node as your server-side web application, that’s where you’d start.